# Is there a way to embed angular components in NativeScript like you can in HTML

Tags: components, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I am trying to convert an Angular website to an android app using NativeScript. Using HTML, I was able to Embed a component simply with:

```
<app-someComponent></app-someComponent>
```

However, with Nativescript nothing happens. Is this possible in NativeScript or do I need to look into using routing? Currently only the actionBar is showing, but if I remove `<app-national-data></app-national-data>` and `<app-state-data></app-state-data>`, then the tabView shows correctly.

*home.component.tns.html*

```
<ActionBar [title]="title"></ActionBar>

<TabView selectedIndex="0" (selectedIndexChanged)="onSelectedIndexchanged($event)">
  <StackLayout *tabItem="{title: 'National', iconSource: 'res://icon'}">
    <StackLayout>
        <Label text="National Data " textWrap="true" class="m-15 h2 text-left" color="blue"></Label>
        <app-national-data></app-national-data>
    </StackLayout>
  </StackLayout>
  <StackLayout *tabItem="{title: 'State', iconSource: 'res://icon'}">
    <StackLayout>
        <Label text="State Data" textWrap="true" class="m-15 h2 text-left" color="blue"></Label>
        <app-state-data></app-state-data>
    </StackLayout>
  </StackLayout>
</TabView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply using `<app-someComponent></app-someComponent>` does have the same effect with NativeScript as it does in HTML.

The issue was a result of an unrelated error in a service being used by the component. The Error was not allowing the component to be displayed. Testing using `tns debug android` instead of using `tns run android` made it easy to find the issue.

Hope my rookie mistake can save someone else some time.